# Django uncaught exception when file upload request canceled

Tags: python, django, google-chrome

I have an async file uploader using Dropzone.js and everything works fine except for a strange server error that appears from time to time when I cancel an upload request. The error is inconsistent, sometimes I get the expected result after canceling the upload request and other times the error shows up in Identical conditions.

**Please note that I'm using chrome's network throttling so I can cancel uploads before the upload finishes.**

This is the file upload view :

```
@login_required
def media_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('media'):

        file = request.FILES.getlist('media')[0]
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        try:
            img = Image.open(file)
            img.verify()

        except Exception as exp:
            return HttpResponse(exp, status=400)

        # Converting and saving media
        img = Image.open(file)
        media_prefix = ('evnt_u' + str(request.user.id))
        media_ext = '.jpg'

        if img.format != 'JPEG':
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            buffer01 = BytesIO()
            img.save(buffer01, format='JPEG')
            file = InMemoryUploadedFile(
                buffer01, None, (media_prefix+media_ext), 'image/jpeg', buffer01.tell, None)

        media = fs.save((media_prefix+media_ext), file)
        return HttpResponse(media, status=200)

    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

I receive `POST /media/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0` correctly with the code above but that's not consistent. the other times I receive the appropriate response followed by a chain of uncaught exceptions:

```
Bad Request: /fa/media/upload/
[05/Apr/2020 18:36:51] "POST /fa/media/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
OSError: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
[05/Apr/2020 18:36:51] "POST /fa/media/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49199)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
OSError: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/Volumes/Storage/WorkSpace/Projects/envs/meetup_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 86, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Volumes/Storage/WorkSpace/Projects/envs/meetup_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does this only happen `if img.format != 'JPEG'`?

Comment: It might be InMemoryUploadedFile: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: @Hoenie I don't think so. judging by the first two lines: `Bad Request: /fa/media/upload/
[05/Apr/2020 18:36:51] "POST /fa/media/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0` the view function returns a value as expected, maybe something is happening with python wsgi handlers

Comment: Gotcha. I remember seeing this same error, but can't remember exactly when. What causes the 400? The `exception`, the `else` statement or a `SuspiciousOperation`?

Comment: @hoenie the `else` clause is where the status 400 comes from. If I cancel the request the `request.files` will be empty so basically the outer if block gets ignored